# Add image to freemarker template for mail?

Tags: spring, freemarker, html-email

Im using spring email with freemarker template engine to send email to customers. As part of the signature I would like to add an image, but can't seem to get the template to find the image. The email appears with an image icon, not the actual image. Any ideas?

In email-html.ftl :

```
<font color="#636466">
  With kind regards,<br /><br />
</font>
<font color="#00747B">
 Name of firm<br />
</font>
<br />
<img src="/images/icon.gif" />
```

The image is available at /servername/contextroot/images/icon.gif

Comment: Should the icon be only a link to some url, or should the image be embedded with the mail (multipart-Mixed)?

Comment: Hi! The icon should be embeddes, as part of the signature. Its the companys logo.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use relative image URLs in an HTML email - there's nothing for them to be relative *to*. You need to change your template to use a fully-qualified URL.

You can also, I believe, embed image data within the email, but that's a whole different question.