# How to add image to a Freemarker template with JavaMail

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, jakarta-mail, freemarker

Now before this question gets marked as a duplicate, 
[Add image to freemarker template for mail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208027/add-image-to-freemarker-template-for-mail)

This question does not provide the Solution to my Problem. 
So I want to add Image as a Background in a Freemarker HTML template which I am attaching to a Google Gmail API Program in Java.

Here is the Code for the Freemarker:-

```
<style>
    body{
background-image: url("cid:${image.jpg}");
}
     .container {
              position: absolute;
              padding:25px;
              margin:25px;
              border:5px;
              text-align: justify;
              text-justify: inter-word;
              font-family: "Times New Roman";
              font-style: italic;
            }
 </style>
```

And the Way I am Inserting an Image using the Google Gmail API is:-

```
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    MimeBodyPart bodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    Template t = freemarkerTemlate.getTemplate("OneEmployee.ftl");
    String mailContent = FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(t, model);
    bodyPart.setContent(mailContent, "text/html");
    multipart.addBodyPart(bodyPart);

    DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(Mailer.class.getClassLoader().getResource("images/image1.jpg").getFile());
    bodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    bodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
    bodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image.jpg>");
    multipart.addBodyPart(bodyPart);
```

My Images are in the Resources Directory which contains another Image Directory

Now I have tried almost all variations of the code possible such as using the

```
<img src="">
```

Adding the cid: within the ${} and also without using the "" but it just does not seem to set the Image in any case.

In some of the Cases it runs without attaching an Image and in some cases it runs but throws an Error on the Console also:-

```
Application failed at {image1.jpg}:- Missing or Null Argument
```

The Model that I am using is:-

```
 Map model = new HashMap();
 model.put("emailNames", emailNames);
```

I havent added anything else to the Model since this is the Only other thing apart from the Image that I am inserting into the freemarker template

Is there anything that I am doing wrong or missing out on ?

**EDIT 2**

I have also tried inserting the Image via the Model by setting it as a Key 
Code has been Attached for Reference

```
Map model = new HashMap();
 model.put("emailNames", emailNames);
 model.put("image.jpg", Mailer.class.getClassLoader().getResource("images/image1.jpg").getFile())
```

It Still fails to work!

**EDIT 2**

Interestingly I noticed that when I do not define `cid` then it does adds the background Image as an Attachment, but whenever I add the `cid` syntax it does not add as an Attachment but it simply ignores the mail.

I read on the net that according to the tutorials you do not pass the Image to be inserted as a part of the model but rather add it as an Attachment defining the content_id (cid) of the Image.

Thank You

Comment: Can you share `model` also how you are setting? In the model have you set `image1.jpg` as a key?

Comment: No sir, I have not set the image1 as key in the Model
Still I am attaching Model also

Comment: Then `${image.jpg}` this part is wrong . You can set image path in the `model` and send to ftl

Comment: What do you expect `url("cid:${image.jpg}")` to do? The error suggest this goes wrong in freemarker even before you have to deal with potential problems with correctly referencing the image so it actually works.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel OP doesn't send anything on the model . Obviously will be null when you access any property .

Comment: @RadheshVineetKhanna In order to get the image URL you must set in the model possibly you can set `model.put("imageUrl","images/image1.jpg")` and In Ftl change  it like `url("cid:${imageUrl}` . And Make sure your paths are correct.

Comment: For the JavaMail part you also need to set the Content-Disposition of the image attachment to inline (there may be other things necessary though, but I don't have time to experiment).

Comment: It does not work, My paths to the respective files are correct

Comment: I don't know anything about the Freemarker part, but the mail message you're creating should be multipart/related.  See the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#sendmpr) for details.

Comment: Yes it is a Multipart Message as a whole in which I have set the Content type to be `text/html`

Comment: @RadheshVineetKhanna it may be multipart, but did you create it as a multipart/related ?

Comment: yes, you were right I was able to change set the Image in the mail but not as a background. Can someone suggest how to set the Image as a background in the mail content ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Finally I was able to get the Answer to the Solution

The way I was loading an Image from the Images Folder in Resources was wrong

```
File file = new ClassPathResource("image").getFile();
```

This is the way to do it
And when passing it to the Freemarker Template you simply need to do `cid:imageURL` that's all and it should work.

Also you should follow the Comments given by @Bill Shannon and  @Mark Rotteveel